# SEO for PHP URLs?

Tags: php, seo

I have many thousands of profile URLs that currently look like this:

```
view_profile.php?id=12345
```

Is there any SEO benefit for me to change them to something like:

```
member12345.htm
```

I can make the change in my .htaccess file but I'm curious if it's even needed?

Comment: Cross-Ref-Close-Chain: [create new page on user entry](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9117874/367456)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easy solution edit your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^member([0-9]+)\.htm(l)?$ view_profile.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
#or /member-1234.html
RewriteRule ^member\-([0-9]+)\-([^/])\.htm(l)?$ view_profile.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
#or /member-1234-user-name/
RewriteRule ^member\-([0-9]+)\-([^/]+)/?$ view_profile.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

`L` mean last rule, so if the regular expression is match, it will stop there.

`NC` mean non case so capital letters like ABC are treated the same as lowercase like abc.

Comment: Thanks for the great examples!  What does the [L,NC] at the end signify?

Comment: Thanks...I'm having an issue with one of these rules so I started a new thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134399/rewrite-rule-for-apache-causing-500-error

Answer (score 2):

If you want these member pages to be found at Search Engines, it'd be good to do a change like this. But only moving the number around would help little , but not much.

To really get an effect, you need to put meaningful words in the URL, e.g. `member-12345-max-weller.htm` for my profile ;-)

This is because Google & Co. supposedly like static pages better than dynamic pages.

Comment: I guess my next question would be what would the .htaccess look like for that?

Comment: @Paul I thought *"I can make the change in my .htaccess file"* meant you could handle that part of it. If you need to know how to edit your .htaccess to accomplish this, do some googling and attempt to learn on your own first. Then post another question if you can't make it work.

Comment: I can do that...I should have been more clear.  It was more of a PHP question I guess. All set, thanks!

Comment: @Paul If your question was answered, please mark the answer as such.

Comment: "static pages better than dynamic pages" this is not determined from the extension of the file, it is determined from the header response from the server.  In the case of rewrite they are identical in those terms.

Comment: Ok, maybe it is not the file extension, but as far as I know it has some impact if there is a query string or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, query urls are not optimal for SEO.

But instead of .htaccess you should use a proper php url mapper.

Take a look at [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/), url mapping is one of its core features. Eg:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/silex.phar'; 

$app = new Silex\Application(); 

$app->get('/hello/{name}', function($name) use($app) { 
    return 'Hello '.$app->escape($name); 
}); 

$app->run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is requirement of static page url that is more effective for robots to understand the pages content. with url you have to also managed the title and description of page. rewrite the url with .htaccess file best better option.