# Rewrite rule for Apache not finding URL?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

Using the answer I received from [rcs20](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1072482/rcs20) in my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133695/seo-for-php-urls) when I add this entry to my .htaccess file I see the error 404 Not Found:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^member\-([0-9]+)\-([^/])\.htm(l)?$ view_profile.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

The URL I'm passing it is:

```
mysite/member-8222-jane.html
```

Any idea why this might be happening.  My old rewrite rule works fine:

```
RewriteRule view_profile=(.*)$ view_profile.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Check your Apache error log and see what it's spitting out.

Comment: looks like: RewriteRule: unknown flag 'NC]

Comment: is that a typo or do you actually have two right square brackets `[L,NC]]`, which could cause the 500 too. Should be just `[L,NC]`

Comment: I just saw that and removed the second bracket which fixes the error but it still doesn't want to rewrite the URL I pass it

Comment: I continue to get a 404 error.  If I change the second regex to (.*)\.htm(l)?$ it works but is this valid?

Comment: Cross-Ref-Chaining: [create new page on user entry](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9117874/367456)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

found it:

The `+` sign needs to be added to `[^/]` => `([^/]+)`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^member\-([0-9]+)\-([^/]+)\.htm(l)?$ view_profile.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

You can also add the extra chars `jane` in `member-8222-jaane.html` by using the $2 like:

```
RewriteRule ^member\-([0-9]+)\-([^/]+)\.htm(l)?$ view_profile.php?id=$1&extra=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Still fails but if I change it to: (.*)\.htm(l)?$ it works.  Any issues with that?